# Bad return of pl/sql function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, return-value

The function always returns 0, no matter what number I will choose

```
create or replace function FNC_PRICE_AVE_BUY(PRICE_AVE in number)
    return number
    is
    V_AVE number(6,2);
begin
    select NVL((avg(AMOUNT_PRICE_BUY)),0) into V_AVE from BUYER
    where AMOUNT_PRICE_BUY = PRICE_AVE;
    return V_AVE;
end FNC_PRICE_AVE_BUY;
/
set serveroutput on;
select FNC_PRICE_AVEC_BUY(31) as Average_price_321 from dual;
```

Comment: What is the result of `SELECT amount_price_buy FROM buyer WHERE amount_price_buy = 31;`?

Comment: It's a average price that buyer was make, and 0 supose to display, when buyer have no transactions, but it's always display 0

Comment: Doesn't answer my question...

Comment: As far as I understand your query, you are asking for the average price where the price IS the given parameter. So, the result should be 0 if nothing was found (correct), or the given parameter (makes no sense, you can have hundreds of records with 31, so you will get 31 as result. You can just ask if there is ANY with your amount (select count ..... > 0 )

Comment: In other words, it seems that you are providing PRICE_AVE values (as function's parameters) that don't exist in BUYER table so query returns 0.

Comment: PL/SQL functions acts a little different when called from SQL. If an error is raised in the function, the error will not propagate and you will get the default of what your return variable is. In your case a NULL. Add an error handler for NO_DATA_FOUND errors and return 0 or something to signal there were no rows.

Comment: *"It's a average price that buyer was make"* . If that is your business rule shouldn't the parameter be something like P_BUYER_ID and shouldn't you be comparing it to BUYER.BUYER_ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select AMOUNT_PRICE_BUY from BUYER where AMOUNT_PRICE_BUY = 31;`

The value of the above query is returning null value, that is why you are getting zero everytime

Answer (score 0):

Based on comment #2 underneath your question I think this is the logic you want:

Create a function that returns the average price for a buyer.

The parameter should be a buyer ID.

The return value the average price for that buyer.

```
create or replace function FNC_PRICE_AVE_BUY(BUYER_ID in number)
    return number
    is
    V_AVE number(6,2);
begin
    select NVL((avg(AMOUNT_PRICE_BUY)),0) into V_AVE from BUYER
    where ID = BUYER_ID;
    return V_AVE;
end FNC_PRICE_AVE_BUY;
```